# What is the etymology and reasoning behind the US Military term,"D-Day"?

Tags: etymology

Today is the 70th anniversary of D-Day, the day Allied forces in WWII invaded Normandy.

It just occurred to me that I have nothing better than guesses for what the "D" actually stands for, and my initial searches turned up a number of reasonable guesses. ("Deployment," "Designated," etc.")

EDIT: It seems that the "D" is generally thought to refer to "day," so the obvious question is "Why call something D-Day if the the D simply makes it mean 'Day Day'"?

Comment: See [D-Day military term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Day_%28military_term%29)

Comment: The name of one of the most famous military campaigns in recent history is really General Reference.

Comment: That's a good suggestion,  medica.

Comment: Well, I learnt something today, then. I’m one of the (apparently numerous) people who had been walking around with a false folk etymology (_debarkation_ or _disembarkation_ in my case) all these years. I could have found that out in about 30 seconds by doing a Google or dictionary search, though, which makes this question off-topic as General Reference.

Comment: @Janus: I learned *two* things today! Firstly, I learned the same thing as you (which I didn't previously know). Secondly, I discover that I have a slightly different definition of "General Reference" to you. For most purposes on ELU, I think of GR as meaning *"easy to look up, but **also common knowledge for native speakers**"*.

Comment: @Fumble I don’t think GR has to be common knowledge for native speakers. “What does _cataphatic_ mean?” would be a question the answer to which I doubt would be common knowledge for most native English speakers; but the word is clearly described in any decent dictionary, so it’s still GR.

Comment: @Janus: I'm not remotely suggesting that my definition of GR is any more "defensible" than anyone else's. But let's face it, the vast majority of questions asked on ELU are either so trivial practically all native speakers know the answer already, or they're easily googleable. And most of the rest net down to "opinion-based" anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - so you mean all those times when a dictionary definition was sought, that 1) you didn't actually mean to close vote, and 2) you always knew the definition of the word?

Comment: @medica: I usually closevote on the basis that the question isn't of interest to *linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts*. And (perhaps uncharitably) I don't usually classify people with highly limited command of English as "serious enthusiasts".

Comment: I'm struggling a little with the notion that this is "general reference" despite multiple folks here indicating *not* knowing the answer, and actually having assumed seemingly incorrect ones.   But, in the interest of improving it, I edited to incorporate *why* such a term would be introduced, given that it seems entirely redundant.

Comment: @Jaydles - when they must designate a day in secret code, it can be *anything*. It happened to be Operation Neptune, but in military tradition, a secret day is D (for day) and day. It's not Gen Ref because everybody knows it; it's Gen Ref because it is everywhere on the internet, including the [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/D-day): "The unnamed day on which an operation or offensive is to be launched." Now the question appears to be about why the military names things the way they do. That I don't know.

Comment: I support leaving this question open.

Comment: @Jaydles Thanks for improving the question. I agree that the confusion and conflicting answers generally available make it a good question to track down the real answer to on ELU.

Comment: Over the radio, you say "D-Day" to prevent confusion with similar sounding words (such as "Bay").  The same is applied to "H-Hour" to protect against things like "Our".  This has spread to other forms of communication.

Comment: @Jaydles Now _that_ is a good question—one that was not answered in any of the sources I came across when I looked earlier and is certainly not going to be just sitting there waiting for anyone who can use a dictionary. Voted to reopen.

Comment: OK, I voted to reopen. I hope someone actually has an answer for this.

Answer (score 13):

The key to understanding "D-Day" is in how other days in the operation are referenced. The "D" does refer to "day", and in planning a complex operation, certain things have to happen on or by earlier dates; these are scheduled as, say, "D-7" for seven days before the op.

These relative date references are more useful than absolute dates for two reasons: one, you don't have to rewrite the whole plan if the target date changes, and two, you can keep the target date secret while discussing logistics with a lot of subordinates.

So all the other days in the op are "D minus 7" or "D plus 3". The target date is "the day we're calling D", or "D-Day."

Comment: Similarly, `T minus 2 hours` from shuttle launches.

Comment: Yep, though secrecy has been less important in the U.S. space program. :) In space launch sequencing, it's also common for the clock to get started and stopped prior to launch -- more than one hour might elapse between T minus 2 hours and T minus 1 hour. I believe after launch the clock isn't ever stopped, though.

Answer (score 5):

According to the U.S. Army ([here](http://www.history.army.mil/faq/ddaydef.htm)) it simply means "Day". "H-Hour" is also used, with the "H" meaning "Hour". I'm not quite sure why the redundancy exists; but that's how it goes, I guess.

Comment: It is to emphasize the big day from any other day in discussions. Since the actual date is decided late, they need a proper name for it before that.

Comment: They could call it "T-Day", or just "The Big Day" :-)

Comment: They could call it 'Norman', but they decided not to.

Comment: I could actually see them calling it "Day D" or "Hour H", along the lines of "Brand X". I'm not sure why they would have reversed the pattern, though.

Comment: Because it is a day, not a D.

Comment: Similarly, "Brand X" is a brand, not an X.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14951/discussion-between-matt-gutting-and-oldcat).

Answer (score -1):

In the military, D-Day is the day on which a combat attack or operation is to be initiated. The best known D-Day is June 6, 1944 — the day of the Normandy landings — initiating the Western Allied effort to liberate mainland Europe from Nazi occupation during World War II.

Basically 
H−8 means 8 hours before H-Hour, and D+7 means 7 days after D-Day.By extension, H+80 minutes is used for H-Hour plus 1 hour and 20 minutes.

So D in D-Day stands for Designated

Read these pages:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_designation_of_days_and_hours

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Day_%28military_term%29

Comment: From your own Wiki link: *"Contrary to popular belief, the "D" does not stand for any specific word – the most popular being disembark. (NATO). According to http://www.history.army.mil/faq/ddaydef.htm the "D" stands for "Day"."* The rest of your answers sounds good. P.S. That down-vote was not mine.

Comment: Ummm, must read more about this now :D

Thank you  @Cerberus :)

Comment: I don't see how you got from your first two paragraphs to `So D in D-Day stands for Designated.`

Comment: Not sure that's correct, in France it was referred to as J-Jour which fits with the D (or J) standing for day (or jour) as indicated by the other responses.